# Parameter to give permissions to Role in order to modify customer information

Tags: customer, backend, magento-2.1.9, parameter

I would like to have a parameter which if selected *Yes*, the dealers of the webpage aren't able to modify any customer information. If selected *No*, nothing happens and they can modify anything they desire about the customer.

I have added the parameter in the backend:

[image]

The code behind the parameter in: `app/code/<vendor>/<module>/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="tabId" translate="label" sortOrder="0">
            <label>TabName</label>
        </tab>
    <section id="section_id">

        <tab>gsp</tab>
        <resource>resource</resource>

        <group id="customer">                

            <field id="permission_info_dealer" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="105"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Allow dealer edit customer data </label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>                

        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

So as I said I would like depending on the user role, be able to remove or hide this *Edit* from

> Admin-> Customers -> All Customers

when the **Yes** is selected:

[image]

The **Edit** button with the xml code:

```
 <action name="edit">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                    <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
```

And I have this code `app/code/<vendor>/<module>/Block/Form/Edit.php`:

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\<module>\Block\Form;


class Edit extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Edit
{
   const PERMISSION_INFO_DEALER = 'gsp_configuration/customer/permission_info_dealer';

    public function canEditInfoDealer()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $scopeConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');

        return $scopeConfig->getValue(self::PERMISSION_INFO_DEALER, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $role = $this->_getRole();
        $gspRole = $this->gspRoleFactory->create()->load($role->getId(), 'role_id');

        $data['permission_info_dealer'] = $gspRole->getData('permission_info_dealer');

        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'gsp_users_index_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('GSP: Additional Permissions'), 'collapsable' => true]
        );

        $yesno = $this->yesnoFactory->create()->toOptionArray();

        $fieldset->addField(
        'gsp_permission_info_dealer',
        'select', [
        'name' => 'gsp_permission_info_dealer',
        'label' => __('Allow dealer edit customer data'),
        'title' => __('Allow dealer edit customer data'),
        'values' => $yesno,
        'value' => isset($data['permission_info_dealer']) ? $data['permission_info_dealer'] : 1
        ]
        );

        $this->setForm($form);

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _getRole()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_role');
    }
}
```